# javascript window.open in safari

Tags: javascript, ipad, safari

I've run into an issue with opening a new window in safari (both ipad and desktop versions) that revolves around the popup blocker. Basically I've found that if window.open isn't called from a click event, safari will block the popup.

The event that is calling window.open is currently onchanged from a list box.

Is there any way other than switching which event we handle to trick safari into allowing a popup in this scenario? (the onchanged event)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to open a new window in mobile safari other than from a button click. Refer to this [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649962/ipad-safari-popup) which is similar. I'm not sure if it will work, but you can look at [triggering a button click programatically using jquery's trigger() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511874/cannot-programmatically-trigger-jquery-click-event).

You might also want to look at options of showing a dialog within your own page, maybe using tools like jquery ui.

HTH!

Comment: Unfortunately, when you try to trigger another elements "click" event, safari also blocks those as popups. The only way to get a popup, is to have a user generated click event on a control, which I would be fine with if when you selected an item from the dropdown on an Ipad, it counted as a "click", however it doesn't fire the click event... :( Time for some degradation code!

Comment: Yeah basically any decent browser will not allow window.open except when the execution can be traced to a user-initiated event.

Comment: In my opinion the real problem seems to be the built-in silent popup blocker.

Comment: Sadly this breaks even when the user generated the click... which triggers an asynchronous action (say pulling data from an IndexedDB)... where the callback tries to open the window :-(

Comment: I believe the safari is "judging" user interaction wrong. Chromes does it better. The user initiated a click in the picker, if its a change event it should count anyway... This breaks so many things

Answer (score 38):

The safari has a pop-up blocker silencer not show when a link is blocked.

To check if the pop-up blocker is active, go on safari settings > security > something like blocking pop-ups.

To cross it in a simple way, since I can not open a new window, I display an alert showing pop-up blocked.

In my case, I use select inputs to open external links:

### HTML

```
<select id="retailer" class="windowOpen retailer-submenu">
    <option value="null">Select one</option>
    <option value="http://amazon.com">Amazon</option>
    <option value="http://ebay.com">eBay</option>
</select>
```

### Javascript

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('select.windowOpen').change(function(){
        var url = $(this).val();

        var open = window.open(url);
        if (open == null || typeof(open)=='undefined')
            alert("Turn off your pop-up blocker!\n\nWe try to open the following url:\n"+url);
    });
</script>
```

---

### The code to check if a pop-up is blocked is just this:

```
var open = window.open('http://google.com');
if (open == null || typeof(open)=='undefined')
    alert("Turn off your pop-up blocker!");
```

---

*PS: the jquery trigger did not work with me.*

Comment: I ended up going with a graceful degradation approach which allowed the user to still use the select to pick where they wanted to go and then a button to actually perform the navigation... That way I'm not popping up any obtrusive messages

Comment: Thanks. I ended up displaying a pop-up in safari browsers with an Open button that ensured the window.open command was performed in a user-initiated stack.

Answer (score -1):

When Safari block the pop uo even if you click the link it appears as its not clicking.you can use below in your capabilities to enable safari popup

```
"safariAllowPopups": "true"
```

To Click on the Allow button in Safari Pop up use below code:

```
 ((IOSDriver<IOSElement>) driver).context("NATIVE_APP");
 ((IOSDriver<IOSElement>) driver).findElement(By.id("Allow")).click();
 try{
          Thread.sleep(5000);
    }catch (InterruptedException e){
          System.out.println(e);
    }
```