# opening an new tab on iPad safari using javascript

Tags: javascript, ipad

i need to open a new browser tab on iPad safari using javaScript, i tried window.open() but it does not work,i am using iPad 2 with iOS 5.1, any help will be appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript window.open in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880316/javascript-window-open-in-safari)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can directly control opening a new window within a new tab using solely the `window.open` method; you could however have a hidden link with the attribute `target="_blank"`, and then simulate a click event with JavaScript on that anchor.

Comment: I can't get this to work in any browser using `$('a').click()` or $('a').trigger('click');` or the sort. Is there some magic I can do to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

With adding to this, sometimes user blocked the new pop up/tab to be open on their respective devices - iPad or iPhone. In the Safari settings, look for the "Block Pop-ups" option. Toggle the switch to enable it. When this option is turned on, Safari should block most pop-ups while you are browsing.

```
// Attempt to open a new window
  var newWindow = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=1,height=1');

  // Check if the new window was successfully opened
      if (newWindow && !newWindow.closed) {
    console.log('Pop-up blocker is not enabled.');
    // Close the new window as we don't need it
    newWindow.close();
  } else {
     console.log('Pop-up blocker is enabled.');
  }
```