# Link inside of a Highcharts tooltip

Tags: jquery, highcharts, lazy-high-charts

I'm trying to replicate the behaviour of this fiddle for my application. It all works fine when I'm on a PC or Mac. I've also tested on a few tablets, but it doesn't want to work on an iPad, which is a large user base for my app.

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/PLUpR/show/][1]
```

Any help would be very appreciated!!!

Comment: Did you try different browsers on your ipad? Safari vs. Chrome?

Comment: Yes i did. It doesnt work on either.

Comment: I tested it on iPad (iOS 7.0.3) and all works properly, which version do you have?

Comment: Tried on iPad and iPhone (iOS 7.1). Maybe the question was not clear. The fiddle shows up, but the point of the fiddle is that there's a data label with a link inside going to google in this case. On a PC i can click on the link and it will go to that page, but on iPad it doesn't react...

Comment: You should really consider putting up what you've already done. That would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By pure coincidence i happened to come across this resource.

Add this [code](https://gist.github.com/ricardoferreira1980/5335186) to your js script and it fixes the issues with clicking on mobile devices!!
After adding this the iPad browser reacted to clicks on canvas and tooltips as expected.

Comment: glad you found a working solution. Did the solution that I provided that uses HTML not work? Want to know the feedback on the answer as I don't have an iOS device to test myself

Comment: unfortunately not. It seems all to do with the way an iPad would interpret the pinching and clicking and zooming etc. Hence the issues. On a PC this would work fine, as in the initial fiddle, but for touch these events change and don't react in the same way. I appreciate the suggestion, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can catch click event on the point and load url link.

```
data : [{
                x : Date.UTC(2011, 3, 25),
                title : 'H',
                url: 'http://www.google.com',
                text : 'google'
            }],
            point:{
                events:{
                    click: function(){
                        var url = this.url;
                        window.open(url,'_blank');
                    }
                },
            },
```

See the example: http://jsfiddle.net/PLUpR/3/

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. This would be correct for the PC experience. However on the iPad you have to click on a point to show you tooltip, which means you show tooltip and immediately send the person on to another page. I need to be able to show the tooltip, if they want to click on the link then is a choice.

Comment: In general it looks like a problem with window.open in the javascript. I preapre example which works on PC (http://jsfiddle.net/PLUpR/12/)

Relted topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880316/javascript-window-open-in-safari

Answer (score 2):

Like Sebastian Bochan mentioned, it seems like a Safari issue, rather a security issue in general, that won't allow opening of windows using javascript. The request to open a new window needs to be user initiated like clicking of a link, and not through a javascript code block;

Although you have set the text to

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"> google </a>
```

Highcharts generates SVG spans for the links in the tooltip, and this spans have an onclick handler that opens a window. See below the default html/svg generated for the flag tooltip

```
<text x="8" y="21" zIndex="1" style="font-size:12px;color:#333333;width:200px;fill:#333333;">      
   <tspan style="font-size: 10px" x="8">Monday, Apr 25, 2011</tspan>
   <tspan onclick="location.href=&quot;http://www.google.com&quot;" x="8" dy="16" style="cursor: pointer;"> google </tspan>
</text>
```

Safari would disallow `onclick="location.href=&quot;http://www.google.com&quot;"`

Luckily, Highcharts allows you to skip the SVG, and use direct html in your tooltip. All you need to do is set [tooltip.useHTML](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#tooltip.useHTML) to true, which is by default false. Voila, the following HTML is now generated for the tooltip, and I believe Safari would not have issues with this, thought I have not been able to try this myself

```
<div class="highcharts-tooltip" style="position: absolute; left: 912px; top: 70px; visibility: visible;">
   <span style="position: absolute; white-space: nowrap; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; left: 8px; top: 8px;" zindex="1">
     <span style="font-size: 10px">Sunday, Mar 24, 18:34:45</span><br>
       <a href="http://www.google.com"> google </a><br>
   </span>
</div>
```

[Demo @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/DExew/)

Answer (score 0):

Simply useHTML not enough.

```
tooltip: {
  useHTML: true,
  style: {
    pointerEvents: 'auto'
  }
},
```