# How can I add links in a Highcharts tooltip that will open on mobile's browser?

Tags: react-native, highcharts, expo, react-highcharts

I am developing a React Native app with expo. One of the screens contains a graphic created with Highcharts. All points have an associated *tooltip* with some text, to which I would like to add a link that would open the URL in the browser (that is, outside the app).

Very basically, the app code looks like this:

```
import ChartView from 'react-native-highcharts';


render() {
        let Highcharts = "Highcharts";
        let config ={
            chart: {
                type: "line",
                animation: Highcharts.svg,
            ...
            tooltip: {
                followTouchMove: false,
                useHTML: true,
                formatter: function () {
                    return `<div class="text">bla bla bla
                                <a href="http://www.google.cat">my link here/a>
                            </div>`;
                }
            },
        };
```

That gets rendered in:

```
    return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <ChartView
            config={config}
        />
    </View>
```

Checkin [Link inside of a Highcharts tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22427025/1983854) I saw interesting ideas like adding this info inside the `charts` key:

```
    events: {
        click: function (event) {
            var url = 'http://www.google.cat';
            window.open(url, '_blank');
        }
    }
```

Which works, but it opens the link inside the `ChartView` of React Native. That is, the space with the graph shows the given URL. However, I want the URL to open in the browser.

Is there a way to open the links in the browser? React Native's `Linking.openURL(url);` is the way to do so, but I cannot see how can I bing `Linking.openURL` from within the `config` settings.

Comment: I found [this](https://github.com/TradingPal/react-native-highcharts/issues/79#issuecomment-379971734). Seems like a possible workaround.

Comment: @bennygenel thanks! Based on this approach and other things I read, I came out with a solution I just posted as an answer. It only works on iOS, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using `onMessage` from the CharView:

```
return(
<View style={styles.container}>
    <ChartView
        onMessage={m => this.onMessage(m)}
        config={config}
    />
</View>
```

This triggers this method to open the URL:

```
onMessage = (m) => {
    let data = JSON.parse(m.nativeEvent.data);
    Linking.openURL(data.url)
};
```

And the URL gets populated through a global variable `window.myURL` and sending the message with [`postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage):

```
render() {
    let Highcharts = "Highcharts";
    let config ={
        ...
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stickyTracking: false,
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function(e) {
                            window.postMessage(JSON.stringify({'url': window.myUrl}));
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
        },
        tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            formatter: function () {
                window.myUrl = extras.url;
                return `<div class="text">bla bla bla
                            <a href="http://www.google.cat">my link here/a>
                        </div>`;
            }
    };
```

It works well on iOS, but not in Android.