# How can I make React Native in Android aware of a click event in a tooltip in a Highcharts chart?

Tags: highcharts, react-native, react-highcharts

I have a React Native application built with Expo. On [How can I add links in a Highcharts tooltip that will open on mobile's browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55358659/1983854) I was able to pass a URL to Highcharts so that when a tooltip is clicked, that URL is opened:

```
return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <ChartView
            onMessage={m => this.onMessage(m)}
            config={config}
        />
    </View>
```

This triggers this method to open the URL:

```
onMessage = (m) => {
    let data = JSON.parse(m.nativeEvent.data);
    Linking.openURL(data.url)
};
```

And the URL gets populated through a global variable `window.myURL` and sending the message with [`postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage):

```
render() {
    let Highcharts = "Highcharts";
    let config ={
        ...
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stickyTracking: false,
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function(e) {
                            window.postMessage(JSON.stringify({'url': window.myUrl}));
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
        },
        tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            formatter: function () {
                window.myUrl = extras.url;
                return `<div class="text">some text</div>`;
            }
    };
```

This works well on iOS (both physical and emulator), but does not on Android (neither physical nor emulator).

I have gone through different Github issues such as [onMessage not called in native code even though sent from webview( android)](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17337) and [react native html postMessage can not reach to WebView](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11594) and they tend to suggest using some timeout on `window.postMessage()`. However, I see that even this does not work:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function(e) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        console.log('bla');
                        window.postMessage(JSON.stringify({'url': window.myUrl}));
                    }, 200);
                }
            }
        }
    },
},
```

Since even `console.log()` does not work, it looks to me as if the `click` event is not being caught by Android.

How can I make Android aware of this event so that I can go through the message and then open the URL?

Comment: Can you change the console.log to an alert or a dom change, to make sure the console.log is not hidden and the click event does fire?

Comment: @basbase thanks! I tried with an `alert` and it was not triggered either.

Comment: Can you create a buildable repo for us to poke at?

Comment: Are you able to declare view of webview or set any callback to webview?

Comment: @SebastianBochan no. I see in highchart's code that [CharView is in fact a WebView](https://github.com/TradingPal/react-native-highcharts/blob/master/react-native-highcharts.js#L81) but if I say for example `<ChartView onLoad={() => {
            Alert.alert('info', 'hey');
            console.log('>>>>>>>>><hello highcharts!!');}}
    />` it does not work, while the same works on `<WebView
        onLoad={() => {
                        Alert.alert('info', 'hola');
                        console.log('>>>>>>>>><hola!!');
        }}>
    </WebView>`.

Comment: @SebastianBochan I see you are a dev on Highcharts!! Do you know if this is a bug or something I am missing to do? Not to bang my head with this if it is not something I can do.

Comment: As I see, you use external react-native wrapper, developed by third party developers. I recommend you to post the problem in their github. 

We are still developing our official react-native wrapper, which should be released soon.

Comment: From what I can see, you are trying to execute the javascript code inside the webview but the configuration is defined in react native. Can you try `eval` to execute the code on click like: `eval("setTimeout(function() {console.log('bla');window.postMessage(JSON.stringify({'url': window.myUrl}));}, 200);")`

Comment: This way, it should execute the string with your code inside the webview

Comment: @DaniAkash thanks a lot, I will give it a try. The interesting point here is: why is it working on iOS but not in Android? That is, something is being sent through the Webview in iOS, but not in Android and does not make sense to me.

Comment: @fedorqui I check the RN github issue [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11594) you post, have you gone through them carefully? A couple tricks are mentioned there. `setTimeout` turns out to be least reliable one.

Comment: Notably the `awaitPostMessage` fix, and the `window.__REACT_WEB_VIEW_BRIDGE.postMessage` fix, both look promising. Have you tried them?

Comment: @fedorqui let me know if it worked :)

Comment: @DaniAkash I tried what you said and added in `plotOptions.series.point.events` the value `click: function(e) {
                                eval("setTimeout(function() {console.log('bla');window.postMessage(JSON.stringify({'url': window.myUrl}));}, 200);")
                            }` but it did not work, nothing showed in the console and the JSON did not get through.

Comment: @hackape `window.__REACT_WEB_VIEW_BRIDGE.postMessage` made it!! Two things: 1) if I say `if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
                                     window.postMessage(data);
                                } else {
                                    window.__REACT_WEB_VIEW_BRIDGE.postMessage(message_data);
                                }` it does not work, but it does if I just say `window.postMessage(data);`. I know it is tangential, but sounds weird to me. 2) Post an answer so that I can award the bounty : )

Comment: @fedorqui thanks! answer posted, glab it works :D. feel free to edit if I missed sth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `"click"` event is fine. Problem is that, RN core's `<WebView>` implementation for Android is flawed at polyfilling `window.postMessage()`. This issue has been well discussed in [this github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11594).

So it seems the nature of problem, is RN has to polyfill the native `window.postMessage` for some reason, but the override didn't take place timely, causing `window.postMessage` calls still made to the native one.

One solution (for Android) proposed in that github issue, is simply stop using the native `window.postMessage`, and directly use the internal interface, which is the actual polyfill function.

```
// in place of `window.postMessage(data)`, use:
window.__REACT_WEB_VIEW_BRIDGE.postMessage(String(data))
```

One heads-up though, this API is not public and might be subject to change in future.