# open new window in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, safari

I have html `SELECT` to open pages in new tab
my SELECT here:

```
<select onchange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'newWindow')">
       <option value="0">select</option>
       <option value="Home.aspx">home</option>
       <option value="http://wwww.facebook.com">FaceBook</option>
</select>
```

my list works fine except **Safari**. I tried it in Android and still works fine.
I found this code for Safari:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPod|Blackberry|Windows Phone/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        var onchange = ["if ($(this).val()!=''){"];
        onchange.push("    var popup=window.open($(this).val());");
        onchange.push("    if (!popup||typeof(popup)==='undefined'){");
        onchange.push("        window.location = $(this).val();");
        onchange.push("    }");
        onchange.push("}");
        $('#listBoxes select').each(function () {
            $(this).attr("onchange", onchange.join(''));
        })
    }
</script>
```

but still not working in Safari. 
Any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: Are you talking about Safari (for OS X / Windows) or Mobile Safari (for iOS)?

Comment: Why in the world are you building a function as a string?

Comment: @Quentin Safari for OSX / Windows), but my target is iOS as well.

Comment: @epascarello, do you mean javascript function? to be honest I just copied it from the web after a lot of search.

Comment: Basically it is a pop up blocker that is blocking it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880316/javascript-window-open-in-safari