# iOS not loading target click URL bc of hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have a fun little button on a website I am developing here:

http://dev.lapiazzaonline.com/merrick.php

When you click on the takeout menu button on desktop and chrome inspector iPhone simulator it works great.... with a nice little delay.

Now on iOS, nothing happens. I think it might have to do with the hover state issue, but more think my JS is messed up.

this is the js in the behavior.js file

```
// cool buttons
    (function() {
      var removeSuccess;

      removeSuccess = function() {
        return $('.button').removeClass('success');
      };

      $(document).ready(function() {

        return $('.button').click(function(e) {

              e.preventDefault();
              var goTo = this.getAttribute("href"); 

              $(this).addClass('success');
              setTimeout(removeSuccess, 1500);

              setTimeout(function(){
              window.open(goTo);
              },1500); 


        });
      });

    }).call(this);
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,
-Muhu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue here is the use of `window.open`. You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880316/javascript-window-open-in-safari) and other similar issues if you search. Unfortunately, there are multiple reports that jQuery trigger will not work either. So, what I would do is just use something like Modernizr, or if you just want to figure out which browser it is, [this is a nice tool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/detect-browser), and then when you're on iOS or a browser with similar blocking functionality, run a different function that doesn't prevent the default, and opens the link normally.