# jQuery won't trigger click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I'm trying to use jQuery to simulate a click on an "Add Row" link. I want to trigger the javascript function attached to the link.

The function that adds the row is in a separate file, so I can't call it directly. (Specifically, [it starts on line 57 of Django's admin inline.js file](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/inlines.js#L57).) I guess my only other option is to trigger a click event on the link.

[image: Table diagram]

However, I tried to do this with:

```
$("tr.add-row a").trigger('click');
```

To no avail. It doesn't trigger the click event.

How can I get jQuery to click the link? (Or, ultimately, how can I add a row?)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem: Django's jQuery was namespaced in `django.jQuery`, not the standard `jQuery` or `$`.

I had to write

```
var jQuery = django.jQuery;
var $ = django.jQuery;
```

in front of my script, and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger("click") should work, you can also try like this:

```
$("tr.add-row a").click();
```

http://api.jquery.com/click/

Most likely $("tr.add-row a") doesn't find anything.

Comment: may be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511874/cannot-programmatically-trigger-jquery-click-event