# IE Automation using Excel VBA: anchor.click calling a function not working javascript web dialog box

Tags: javascript, excel, ie-automation, vba

I am relatively new to IE Automation, javascripts and frames. I also am not sure if I have the same issue as [VBA - Handle Javascript pop up with IE automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28899726/vba-handle-javascript-pop-up-with-ie-automation). Pls read on.

Pre-Requisites: IE11, VBA for Excel (2010)

So I am trying to access the details of a webpage dialog box, wherein you are to:
1. Click a button (to validate address given a zip code)
2. A custom webdialog box containing a frame opens asking you to select from a list of cities in which that particular zip code is applicable. The list of cities isn't a combobox but anchor elements displayed in a table. 
3. So I click the particular city using element.click but nothing happens.

Clicking that same anchor element with a manual mouse click triggers the javascript event onclick, which by the way calls another function.

HTML:

```
<a class="thisClass" onclick="return thisFunction("1", "arg2", "targetFrame");" href="thisURL#">
```

And the JavaScript:

```
function thisFunction( arg1, arg2, targetFrame)  {   
    var thisVar1 = new Object();      
    thisVar1.argument1= arg1;   
    thisVar1.argument2= arg2;   
    window.returnValue = thisVar1 ;      
    window.close();    
}
```

And my code:

```
Set frameEl = IE.Document.getElementById("frameID") 'this is accessing the frame of the webpage dialog popup
Set elem = frameEl.contentDocument
Set anchorElemCollection = elem.getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each anchorElem In anchorElemCollection
    If anchorElem.className Like "thisClass" Then
         If anchorElem.innertext Like aParticularValue Then
               anchorElem.Click
               Exit For
         End If
    End If
Next
```

The anchorElem.Click part isn't working. The webdialog popup window doesn't select the anchorElem, and it doesn't close. HELP! What did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you actually looking in the right place for the right element? Is the `.Click` not working or is the correct `anchorElem` never found and no click is ever performed? Step through your code with F8 or add a debug.print above `anchorElem.Click` that shows the element was actually found.

Comment: I used a breakpoint in the debugger (F12) and yes it did step and performed a click. I just dont understand why it didnt actually clicked the anchor.

Answer (score 1):

If you can determine the values that would be passed into *arg1* and *arg2*, try running the javascript routine directly.

```
ie.document.parentWindow.execScript "javascript:thisFunction(some_value1, some_value2, frameEl)
```

Comment: I'm gonna try this now. getting back on you later on the results. thanks!

Comment: Hi @Jeeped. I have tried the execScript but I have the same problem as before, nothing happens! Yes I am sure of the params passed because I derived the function from the outerHtml of the anchor tag. Also, I cannot put a breakpoint on the exact line to which the code runs on the webdialog popup. Is this normal? Cannot trace it efficiently, step-by-step.

Comment: Hi again. I have read at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511874/cannot-programmatically-trigger-jquery-click-event that programmatically clicking a link that contains an href is not possible. If any, can there be workarounds with these?

Comment: I've had limited success clicking links that execute script. That is why I prefer the `.execScript` method.

Comment: Yeah I also tried doing it that way (execScript) but still to no avail - debugger tells that it clicked the link but nothing happens anyways. Perhaps link.click does not behave the same way as button.click.